# Jam tracks / low volume computer

Tags: practice, computer

I am looking to bring more volume to the jam tracks that I am running off my computer. I have 2 amps, I thought maybe of using one of them as a speaker or are there other ways to make this happen?

Comment: What kind of amps are they?

Comment: A Fender Mustang GT is the one I thought about using. The other is an older Crate amp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the headphone port on computer into input on amp. Start with all volumes down, gradually increase. Probably minijack to standard 1/4" jack.